# Why are my iPhone UITableView prototype cell images horizontally shifted?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiimage, prototype

Added flags to my table cells.  Used storyboard to put a UIImageView in the otherwise empty prototype cell and size it nicely (47x34).  Then added code here:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell1";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
            initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [[[content objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"rowValues"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cellTxt = cell.textLabel.text;

    UIImageView *flagImg = (UIImageView *) [cell viewWithTag:10];
    NSString *imgFilenm = [cellTxt stringByAppendingString:@".jpg"];
    flagImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed: imgFilenm ];
    cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 47, 34);   //  not needed, and doesn't fix it

    return cell;
}
```

The images appear, but squeezed to the left to only about 8 pixels.  Why?  And how to correct it?  Thanks!
[image: small flags]      an original:  [image: Belize]

**  EDIT  **
I switched the cell text to UILabel that I added.  Here's that code:

```
UILabel *nameLbl = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:5];
nameLbl.text = [[[content objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"rowValues"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

and what it looks like in the storyboard:  [image: protocell]

But now the flag doesn't even appear.

Comment: you should have enough reputation now to upload.

Comment: Hey, thanks, Paul!  Take a look.

Comment: Here might be the problem: my storyboards default to Retina displayed iPhones, even though I'm choosing 5.0 deployment targets.  Not used to that "feature" and not sure I like it.  Can be changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work using:

```
UIImageView *cellImage = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:10];
[cellImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg", [self.countries objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]]]]];
```

Don't know why the other method doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your flags are not being "squished".  They are actually being hidden behind the title of the cell.  Try something like:

```
UIImageView *flagImg = (UIImageView *) [cell viewWithTag:10];
NSString *imgFilenm = [cellTxt stringByAppendingString:@".jpg"];
flagImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed: imgFilenm ];
[cell bringSubviewToFront:flagImg];
```